# How can we prove,if $m$ and $n$ is non-negative integer and $m≠n$ then $m²≠n²$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

It seem intuitive but can we prove that by logic strictly?

$m∈N , n∈N$

$∀m∀n(m≠n→m²≠n²)$

Comment: yes,i can translate it to logic statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $m^{2}=n^{2}$ they $m =n$ or $m=-n$. In the second case $0 \leq m=-n\leq 0$ so $m=n=0$. So we get $m=n$ in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove it by contradiction. Suppose $m^2=n^2$ and $m \ne n$

you will get m+n=0 which is impossible as m and n are unequal non-negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

With basic properties of inequalities:

We may suppose, for instance, that $m<n$.

If $m=0<n$, the have $m^2=0<n^2$.

If $0<m<n$, as all numbers are positive, we have $0<m^2<mn$. For the same reason, $mn<n^2$. By transitivity, $m^2<n^2$.